# Does D&D 3.5e have rules for firearms?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, firearms

A friend of mine is planning for a campaign in a colonial/pirate setting, and is planning on re-skinning crossbows as firearms, (i.e. light crossbow = musket, hand crossbow = flintlock), but I was wondering if there were already rules for such weaponry.

Comment: You may find [this thread](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19573362/Guns_Should_be_Allowed_in_D38;D) interesting. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 3.5e Dungeon Master's Guide has *some* rules for firearms in the *Building a Different World* section (p144).

Page 145 provides details for Renaissance weapons: pistol, musket, bomb and smokebomb. It also provides some details and considerations for how gunpowder and firearms work. They're stronger or as strong as a heavy crossbow, but have some different drawbacks.

In addition, the following page details Modern and Futuristic weaponry (from revolvers to antimatter rifles). The game is much less prepared for how powerful these are, though! You may be able to use the futuristic weapons if you reskin them as powerful magic weapons.

Bear in mind this is all a *starting point*. The chapter containing these rules is provided as a sort of springboard rather than a complete ruleset.

Comment: They'd make good "magic items" in a Return to the Barrier Peaks adventure, though.

Comment: My friend saw the DMG rules for firearms. He liked the stats, but since the campaign was more colonial than Renaissance, he lowered the weight and price of them and made them Martial weapons since by this point they were theoretically more efficient and commonplace than in the Renaissance period.

Answer (score 6):

*Pathfinder* has some gun rules available, as well as an entire gun-themed base class. Both are fairly weak (about the power level of a 3.5 soulknife) but if it's gotta be Guns or Bust, it might be worth looking into.

Comment: The strong point for firearms in PF is that you target a victims *touch AC* rather than their full AC, which is rather nice. I don't think that's the same in 3.5

Answer (score 6):

Pre-existing sources of d20-compatible blackpowder weaponry include (just what I can remember right now):

- *Dungeon Master's Guide* (p. 144 and on)
- *Pathfinder*
- *d20 Modern* system
- *Iron Heroes* campaign setting

Frankly speaking, for a setting you describe the *DMG* rules are more than enough. You will have to work a bit if you want more detail, and you will definitely have to add cannons (reskinning existing siege weapons, probably), but open *DMG* and you're set.

Comment: Pathfinder is probably the best bet for more in depth 3.5 compatible rules -- I'd list that before d20 Modern or Iron Heroes, which will make some (possibly hidden) assumptions about the rules.

Comment: Agreed, such an assumption won't be what I intend. Bumped Pathfinder.

Comment: I believe the Mystara campaign setting also has some applicable rules. Plus an official 3.5 site approved by WotC, to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the DMG (see previous answers by others), [issue **#321** of **Dragon Magazine**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003R6ANRY) dealt with guns. You should try and get a copy of it (see my link, but you might want to run a google search as well for other options / sellers.)